# Redirect home page to front controller

Tags: java, model-view-controller, servlets

I've a front controller mapped on an URL pattern of `/Controller` which is thus available on `http://localhost:8080/myproject/Controller`. How can I configure my web application so that the homepage on `http://localhost:8080/myproject` get automatically redirected to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the easiest ways is to just register it as a `<welcome-file>` in `web.xml`.

```xml
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Controller</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```